# Find $47 n \pmod {41}$ if $n \equiv 13 \pmod {41}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

As stated in the title, I'm trying to find $47 n \pmod {41}$ when I know that $n \equiv 13 \pmod {41}$

Comment: n=41k+13 for some integer k.

Comment: Multiply the remainder (13) by 47 and then divide this by 41 to see what remains

Comment: Ideally, we ask that you include your thoughts and efforts. Please consider this in future posts.

Comment: Three people have voted to close this as 'unclear what you're asking'. I really don't understand what's unclear to them.

Comment: This post was quite clear, though I edited it to make it even more explicit. Voting to reopen

Answer (score 2):

Let $n=41k+13$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$. $$47n=41(47k)+13\cdot 47$$

$$=41(47k+13)+13\cdot 6=41(47k+13)+78$$

$$=41(47k+13+1)+37$$

Answer (score 2):

You have to find for what number $r$ between $0$ and $40$ the relation
$$
47n\equiv r\pmod{41}
$$
holds.

You already know that $n\equiv 13\pmod{41}$ and $47\equiv 6\pmod{41}$, so
$$
47n\equiv 6\cdot 13\equiv 78\equiv 37\pmod{41}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The thing to remember is that you can multiply congruences quite easily if the moduli are all the same. So $47 \equiv 6 \pmod{41}$ and $n \equiv 13 \pmod{41}$. Then you have $6 \times 13 = 78$. Since that's more than 41, just subtract 41 until you're below 41, in this case just once, giving $47n \equiv 37 \pmod{41}$.